# Displaying multiple records from database in html using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am using php to return records from a database but I would like those records to get displayed in different HTML paragraph blocks 
Currently I am getting echo of results but I want to somehow display them in different places on the website, how can I do this using php and HTML?
Here is my code:

php: $conn is db connection

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM reviews ORDER BY id_review DESC LIMIT 3 ) as result ORDER BY id_review";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
        echo "id: " . $row2["id_review"]. " - Name: " . $row2["content"]. " " . $row2["users_id_user"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

And what I want is:

```
<p><?php echo $row[row1];?></p> // instead of row1 i want first record of my select and so on
<p><?php echo $row[row2];?></p>
<p><?php echo $row[row3];?></p>
<p><?php echo $row[row4];?></p>
```

with arrays:

```
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
{
    $myArray[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
}
print_r($myArray[0]['id_review']);
echo '<br>' ;
print_r($myArray[0]['content']);
echo '<br>' ;
print_r($myArray[0]['users_id_user']);
echo '<br>' ;
```

Comment: Store the results in an array and echo the array part in the HTML element where you wish it to appear.

Comment: Thanks, it works like it should. I edited first post using arrays.